# DXA 1.4 How to use an empty region

Tags: dxa, dxa-java, dxa-1.4

I was using the previous DXA version where it was possible to use empty regions

```
<tri:entities region="HeaderRegion"/>
```

Doing a migration to 1.4, we just changed the tag to:

```
<dxa:entities region="HeaderRegion"/>
```

But we realised that this is not working anymore. When we try to render the page we've got the error

```
Region not found on page: GeneralHeader
```

How can we have the same behaviour as before?

Comment: Hi, I don't see the text after "changed the tag to:" can you edit the question and add the missing information?

Comment: Is the region name mentioned in the error really different from the one in your dxa:entities tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `dxa:entities` Tag is intended to be used in a Region View in order to render all Entities within that Region. You don't specify a Region Name in the tag, because it acts on the current Region.

In DXA 1.2+ the best way to deal with empty Regions is to predefine your (potentially) empty Regions in your Page Template metadata. This will ensure that empty Regions exist in the DXA Page Model and hence they will get rendered with an appropriate Region View even when they are empty.

Alternatively, you can use the `dxa:Region` tag with a `emptyViewName` parameter to render a Region with a given name, even if the Region does not exist in the DXA Page Model.

Comment: I tried with the emptyViewName parameter but it's not working. I've got an error because it's trying to find the file, and it doesn't exist. I registered the region in the CoreInitializer and I used the tag as following: <dxa:region name="IdentificationRegion" emptyViewName="IdentificationRegion" />

Comment: Which file doesn't exist? I assume you have a IdentificationRegion.jsp View?

Comment: No, I don't. With the previous version there was 2 kinds of regions. There where regions that simply don't exist as region views but helped to organise the content in the page. And regions which effectivily had content in it, then they had a related region view. I was trying to implement the first type with the current version, but although I used the attribute emptyViewName, it's not working. It expects to find the IdentificationRegion.jsp. I declared as well in the page template metadata this region in the field specified for that, but I don't get it working.